# How do I change table names of simplemembershipprovider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Is it possible to change default tables(UserProfile, webpages_Membership, etc...) names in creation time with additional fields?

If it is possible How can I do this?

Comment: You can write your own custommembershipprovider, but I am not sure if you can do that form a simplemembershipprovider. Google custom membershipprovider and you will get a lot links and tutorials

Comment: you can't change name of columns because standard MemberShip Api works with them.but you can add additional columns to them by hand or by code first approach with migration.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. The table names are hard coded in the SimpleMembershipProvider.

You could go get the source, modify the names, and use your own version if you wanted. The source is here:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e0115a823029#src%2fWebMatrix.WebData%2fSimpleMembershipProvider.cs

Answer by Mystere Man [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872014/can-i-change-the-webpages-membership-table-name-prefix-in-asp-net-mvc-4)